# Extract data from Yahoo-Finance using VBA (No table object)

Tags: excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I typically use a "QueryTables.Add" approach when pulling data from websites using VBA.
For instance, if you needed historical stock price information from yahoo finance, the VBA code would be something like this:

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URLgoesHere" _
        , Destination:=Range("$M$34"))
end with
```

and so on.... However, the issue arises when I try to get data from a URL that lacks a "table object". For instance, the "[Financial tab](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/financials?p=TSLA)" on Yahoo-Finance displays tables of three financial statements for a particular firm.

I tried using "inspect element"on the [site](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/TSLA/financials?p=TSLA) to look for any table objects, but none were found. Does anyone know how I could scrape the table/data from Yahoo-finance into Excel using VBA? (Without copying and pasting it into excel).

I appreciate all input!